# How can I allow multiple float inputs in a command line argument?

Tags: python, user-input, command-line-arguments

I want to add custom command line arguments to my python script.

Executing the script should look like "python script.py -arg1(input1,input2,input3)" where input1,input2 and input3 are float inputs the user types in.

The inputs are supposed to correspond to numpy.linspace parameters (start,stop,num) to be used in a for loop later.

I am using the argparse package to attempt this.

Here is where I am:

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description = 'Test')
parser.add_argument('-arg1', '--arg1', help = 'Set arg1 value range', required = True)
args = vars(parser.parse_args())

if args['arg1'] == #user input 
 #do something
```

I am drawing a blank at how to get int/float user input in this command line argument. If anyone can give some guidance I would be grateful.

Comment: add `type=float`

Comment: and `nargs=3`. also, you can just use `parser.arg1`

Comment: Do you literally mean `-arg1(0.1,3.14,-0.0)` with parentheses (that would have to be quoted in common Unix shells)?

Comment: @DavisHerring initially yes, but I suppose it would be simpler for it to be "-arg1 0.1 3.14 30" without the commas and parentheses